# TFS Merge Deadlock

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, merge

I am attempting to perform a merge in TFS.  After completing the Merge Wizard I received conflicts with most of my files.  They were all “Existing File” conflicts with the error below

“a non version controlled file or writable file by the same name already exists locally”

I chose to overwrite all local files.  When I open the target solution all of the changes I am attempting to merge are not there and I receive build errors.   However, when I select “Check-In”  -  I can see them under Included Changes as [merge, edit] or [merge,branch].  It’s like they’re in some indeterminate state.

I’m not exactly sure how to get pass this.  I tried to check-in the changes and I receive an error telling me to “Get Latest.”  When I try “Get Latest” – I receive the message “Unable to perform the get operation because the file already exists locally”

Any ideas on how to get past this deadlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target branch which in your local work space compare with the one in source control explorer must be some conflicts.

A simple way to solve it. You can delete your local mapped target branch(copy a backup to a different folder ).Then get latest version of the target branch from source control. Do the merge again, check in the pending changes.

Comment: Thanks!  That solution pretty much worked for me.  However in Source Control Explorer I still see the older merge files as checked out, even though they are not checked out locally after following your suggestion.

Comment: Just noticed... these are files checked out on a different workspace and are out of date.  I performed an undo operation on each of them and it appears to be okay.